# Why Don't Impala Table Definitions Replicate?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, impala

I created a simple four-node Hadoop cluster with CDH 4.7, including Impala 1.1. I'm able to copy CSV files to HDFS and create and query Impala tables over the as described in [the tutorial](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Impala/latest/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_tutorial.html). But I can't query the same table on a different data node:

```
[example.com:21000] > select * from tab1;
Query: select * from tab1
ERROR: AnalysisException: Table does not exist: default.tab1
```

I thought perhaps I needed to reissue the `CREATE TABLE` statement on the second node, but then it suddenly knows the table's there:

```
[example.com:21000] > CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tab1
                    > (
                    >    id INT,
                    >    col_1 BOOLEAN,
                    >    col_2 DOUBLE,
                    >    col_3 TIMESTAMP
                    > )
                    > ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                    > LOCATION '/user/dwheeler/sample_data/tab1';
Query: create EXTERNAL TABLE tab1
(
id INT,
col_1 BOOLEAN,
col_2 DOUBLE,
col_3 TIMESTAMP
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '/user/theory/sample_data/tab1'
ERROR: AlreadyExistsException: Table tab1 already exists
```

So it knows it's there, but I can't query it --- or refresh it:

```
[example.com:21000] > refresh tab1;
Query: refresh tab1
ERROR: AnalysisException: Table does not exist: default.tab1
```

Is there some command I need to execute to get all of the `impalad`s runnig on data nodes to make a queryable table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I filed a [bug report](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-647) and got back an answer:

> In Impala 1.1 and earlier you need to issue an explicit "invalidate metadata" command to make tables created on other nodes visible to the local Impala daemon.
>
> Starting with Impala 1.2 this won't be necessary; the new catalog service will take care of metadata distribution to all impalad's in the cluster.

So it was `INVALIDATE METADATA` that I had failed to notice. Glad to hear it won’t be necessary in 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had what I thought was the same issue, but it wasn't resolved by

```
invalidate metadata;
```

It turned out that my hive was accessing a local derby database, which impala could not see.

The smoking gun:

On the system where I had imported the table through hive, I had

```
cat /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml
[...]
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
   <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db;create=true</value>
    <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
[...]
```

The solution:

I re-deployed the hive client configuration from Cloudera Manager.

Afterwards:

```
  cat /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml
  [...]
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://[snipped-host-name]:[snipped-port]</value>
  </property>
```

Apparently Cloudera Manager is supposed to deploy the client configuration but in some versions it sometimes fails to do so.